# Types have separate declarations of a private property - urql vs @urql

Tags: typescript

It appears I have a type conflict between @urql and urql. How can I resolve this?

```
Type 'import("d:/Development/ribbit/web/node_modules/@urql/core/dist/types/types").Exchange' is not assignable to type 'import("d:/Development/ribbit/web/node_modules/urql/node_modules/@urql/core/dist/types/types").Exchange'.
  Types of parameters 'input' and 'input' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("d:/Development/ribbit/web/node_modules/urql/node_modules/@urql/core/dist/types/types").ExchangeInput' is not assignable to type 'import("d:/Development/ribbit/web/node_modules/@urql/core/dist/types/types").ExchangeInput'.
      Types of property 'client' are incompatible.
        Type 'import("d:/Development/ribbit/web/node_modules/urql/node_modules/@urql/core/dist/types/client").Client' is not assignable to type 'import("d:/Development/ribbit/web/node_modules/@urql/core/dist/types/client").Client'.
          Types have separate declarations of a private property 'onOperationStart'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue from having multiple versions of @urql/exchange-graphcache installed as dependencies. I solved the problem by simply removing them and reinstalling them.

```
yarn remove @urql/exchange-graphcache
yarn add @urql/exchange-graphcache
```